# Missing .qmake.stash file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, qt-vs-addin, visual-c++-2019

Who creates .qmake.stash file? When is it created?

I've been working with Qt in Visual Studio creating Windows applications for some years now but never had to care about this file. But now I have set up a cross compilation in Visual Studio using WSL 1 in order to build my application for Linux on arm64.
I'm able to build all projects in my VS solution on my development computer. Now I'm trying to setup this cross compilation system on another PC. The first project of this solution could be built without a problem, but the second one failed with

```
error : qmake: Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'aarch64....'
error : qmake: Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
error : qmake: Error creating Makefile
```

After many hours of investigation comparing project files and configurations I was able to find the reason: qmake didn't find the file .qmake.stash when it should create the Makefile.

The working project has a .qmake.stash file in the intermediate output path $(IntDir) /obj//<vs_configuration>, e.g. myproject/obj/x64/RelArm64.
The failing project doesn't have this file in its $(IntDir).
If I manually copy this file from the working project to the other project, it works, too.

Who should have placed this file to $(IntDir) before executing qmake?

My qmake.stash file in the working project is quite old. So it seems as if it isn't generated during every build process.

Comment: Where can I read more about qmake.stash?